# Can't execute a command in an android terminal emulator as it seems to require more rights that the app has

Tags: java, android, terminal, permissions

I am using "Terminal Emulator for android" on a 6.0.x Android device.
I've executed "su" so that terminal has root access.
I am trying to execute "wm screen-capture 0 false" but it says:

> Java.lang.SecurityException: Only system can call setScreenCaptureDisabled.

The question is: What should I do in order to be able to execute that command?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
su 1000 -c 'wm screen-capture 0 false'
```

I've managed to do it on my own. Here is the answer in case someone is going to need that too.
In order to decrease chances of that command being reversed: Use Xposed module such as XPrivacy and you'll lowen the chances of that happening considerably.